# What routes must be set (in Linux) to allow Internet access through given interface without setting it default?

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn, network-interface

I am trying to solve a task with routing and OpenVPN's configuration.

After setting the connection, I don't want it to become defaut route to anything, but rather want to use its interface for this kind of activity: `curl  --interface tun20 http://someaddress`.

However, without default route configured, it seems that the host system is unable to send/receive packets *(I think it can't receive them back from VPN, because the sniffer at `someaddress` somehow receives the tcp connection attempt packet which is never continued by data).*

With default route set, VPN works OK - tested that.

**ifconfig**:

```
tun20     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.200.2.236  P-t-P:10.200.2.236  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:258 (258.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

With default route from server:

**route -n**:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.200.0.1      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun20
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.200.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 tun20
66.187.67.130   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
128.0.0.0       10.200.0.1      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun20
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

When the default's route is discarded by `route-nopull` directive, I get this:

**route -n**:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.200.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 tun20
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

---

So I want routing/forwarding recommendations on bringing this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a nice experience to learn.
From https://superuser.com/a/374566/49318, I've found a link to something worth a hour of reading `man ip` and `ip help`:

```
echo 11 mpdevtun7 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via %yourIP% dev tun17 table mpdevtun7
ip rule add from %yourIP% lookup mpdevtun7 prio 1000
```

Now, `curl --interface tun7` works fine. That's all, folks.